# I cant connected to firebase Only this line implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0:15.0.0'

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

First, what caused this error?

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0:15.0.0'

Second, I just want to know how to resolve this kind of problem because I need to connect my app to Firebase.

[image: Screenshot of build.gradle file]
[When I add this Implement implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4 , I lose my connection to  firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXxtn.jpg)
[image: Screenshot of build.gradle file]

Comment: Why do you have the version number twice? Try removing the `:15.0.0` at the end of the line.

Comment: I remove:15.0.0 but the problem not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the version declared twice: `15.0.0:16.0.0`. Gradle has no idea what's going on there. Implement the following instead:

```
implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4
```

16.0.4 is the latest.

Comment: When I add this Implement implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4 , I lose my connection to  firebase

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I do have faced the similar problem and I think the below suggestion can help you to figure it out. What I understand from this is the consistency of version numbers on all firebase libraries. I used the firebase messaging library along with the core library of the different versions, but when I changed the version number as suggested it was working just fine.